# Train neural network to predict multiple distributions

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, distribution, loss, cross-entropy

I aim to train a neural network to predict 2 distributions (10 quantiles, i.e. deciles) at 5 time points. So my `y` is of shape:

`(batch size, time points, distribution values) => (batch size, 5, 20)`

The distributions are standard quantiles, summing to 1 but will not be normally distributed - more like a negative binomial distribution so will hold values like: `[0.0,0.2,0.55,0.1,0.1,0.05,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]`

I believe the best way to do this is using a sigmoid activation on the output layer for each distribution separately and then concatenating, like the following tensorflow model code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#x is of size (batch size, 5, 100) -> 5 is the 5 time points, 100 here is arbitrary
x
output_dists = 2
n_quants = 10
all_ = []
for i in range(1,output_dists+1):
    #use a dense layer of size equal to the number of quantiles for each output channel
    #use output layer with softmax activation
    chan_quant = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_quants, activation='softmax',
                                       name=f"quant_out_{i}")(x)
    #append channel
    all_quant.append(chan_quant)

# concat on axis to to go from 2 (batch size, 5, 10) to (batch size, 5, 20)
output_quant = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(all_quant, axis=2,name="quant")
```

I then use cross-entropy loss for back prop since quantiles sum to 1.

My question is how best to structure the shape of data and train a neural network to predict multiple distributions at multiple time points. For example, whether I should concatenate the two distributions in this way so there are 20 values in axis 2 or should I instead concatenate so there are `(batch size, 5, 2, 10)` for the loss function? Also is the shape with the different time points of distributions (5) valid for the loss function?